# FluentMigrator - how does it know which migration to execute

Tags: c#, .net, fluent-migrator

How does FluentMigrator know what migrations to execute / migrate when you start up the application?

Example: I got two migrations already performed (1 and 2). Now I create a third migration and give it an id of `3`. When I launch my application, FluentMigrator will execute the migrations, but how does it know to skip the first two?

```cs
using FluentMigrator;

namespace test
{
    [Migration(3)]
    public class AddLogTable : Migration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            Create.Table("Log")
                .WithColumn("Id").AsInt64().PrimaryKey().Identity()
                .WithColumn("Text").AsString();
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            Delete.Table("Log");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It stores all information in “`VersionInfo`” table by default. Using this information, it can determine what migrations need to be applied to that database and will then execute each migration in succession that it needs to apply. Also, you can [manage metadata of this table](https://fluentmigrator.github.io/articles/version-table-metadata.html) if you need

Answer (score 1):

A table called VersionInfo is created in the database where information about each migration is recorded. Before applying the migration, a check will be performed to see what records are already in this table.

Comment: That one is created when you use Entity Framework, but does the same occur with FluentMigrator?

Comment: uses the same approach only the table is called VersionInfo